# Real time tracking of android phone using web service

Tags: android

I am working on android app which will track a friend and send longitude and latitude on web application. My app will also fetch data from web application after some time and display a pointer for presenting friend on map according to fetched data. I am thinking about this scenario.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an existing app for that ?

Comment: Something like [Google Latitude](https://www.google.co.nz/latitude/b/0)?

Comment: I am working on aap in which have to track a person at real time on map.

Comment: I have to track friend at real time, if my friend will move then in my case map will update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sending phone's position to webservice (or other external "proxy") is the only one solution for phone's tracking. However you must consider battery life issues. GPS receiver and 3G data communication consumes a lot of energy, so an optimization is essential.

You can also consider sending device to device messages through GCM (no need for your own server and async communication out of the box).
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

With standard webservice - GPS receiver delivers position with 1/s frequency. If you will send your position every 1s. your battery will drain i very short time (depends on device, but expect minutes not hours). Second device have to frequently ask the webservice for current positions of your colleagues, so will drain battery to. You have to reduce number of positions send to web service (i.e. check if it has changed enough) and use some async solution for sending data from webservice to a device that want to be informed about position changes.

Comment: thanks for reply. Kindly tell me use of webservice is best solution for tracking, means can there any issue regarding time of update.

Comment: thanks. Can you tell me what i have to do for real time tracking

Comment: Write an android app for listening location changes and pass messages with location to application on an another device. Then just present result to the user.